# Using third party libraries (composer) inside Joomla module

Tags: php, joomla, composer-php

I am a Joomla beginner. Have created simple hello world module, and it works fine.

I would like to use some third party libraries inside my module.
Usually, I use composer for this and get packages submitted on packagist.org.

What is the best practice to do it inside Joomla module?
And how do I distribute dependencies then?

If there is some example or existing module which uses third party libraries, link would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this really is an opinon question.   I do think that you need to understand joomla a bit more, for example you  mention modules but I bet you really mean components or extensions.  Right now you really need to package any 3rd party libraries you need with your extension when you distribute it.   You can add them as libraries and register them just like the joomla libraries that are there.

Comment: @Elin No, I mean module. I created one following this http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module instructions. I want to use third party libraries inside it. That is what is my question about.

Comment: No matter what, you need to acutally package them with your module, so you can either add them as another library using a library installation package (see how phpmailer is included in the libraries folder) or else store them with with your module and include them.

Comment: @Elin PHPMailer is stored in libraries forlder, there is also some `administrator/manifests/libraries/phpmailer.xml` file, and some queries in schema. To include it like this I would probably need to modify Joomla, then probably have problems with update. Packaging it with my module sounds better. Any example of such modules? Thanks.

Comment: yeah you would need a simple xml file to run the installer, but that doesn't mean modifying joomla any more than installing an extension does.

Comment: @Elin Any example? I guess someone already done that.

Comment: I think that mbabker's podcase manager does that.

Comment: @Elin Hehum, looks like a collection of modules. Isn't there any module which uses some popular PHP library such as monolog, swiftmailer, symfony components, zend components...? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's your own library or an outside one, the handling is the same. https://github.com/mbabker/Podcast-Manager/tree/master/lib_getid3  look at how he handles that.

Comment: @Elin So, he just zips library and then declares it there https://github.com/mbabker/Podcast-Manager/blob/master/pkg_podcastmanager.xml#L25 ? How he uses it then? Is it unzipped after install?

Comment: Yes just like all the other extensions.

Comment: Its strange they didn't implemented composer integration.

Comment: How do you know if end users have support? it's just not a practical approach when you want to have mass plug and play adoption.

Comment: @Elin Support for what? Composer? It can be distributed with Joomla. Its one phar file.

Comment: @Elin I tried with https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/824566716a51e94b3224 but vendor.zip is still vendor.zip after installation. Its not unpacked, so I cant use it. Any idea?

Comment: @Elin Ugh, look like it has to have this https://github.com/mbabker/Podcast-Manager/blob/master/lib_getid3/getid3.xml But list each file there is not an option for me, there are so many files in zend framework :)

Comment: @Elin Does not work even with this xml file, which in my case looks like this https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/0034fe62d0739204715b